# Vue.js 2 - Remove initial margin from body tag

Tags: html, css, vuejs2

My apologies if this is a stupid question, I'm still pretty new to Vue. I created a Vue (with the command `vue init webpack <project-name>`) project and started adding components, the first of which is a navbar. But then I noticed that the body tag has `margin: 8px` by default which causes there to always be a 8px white space between my page and the browser on all sides. I can't for the life of me figure out how to get rid of this margin, I've tried using the following css:

```
* { margin: 0 !important; }
```

And

```
body { margin: 0 !important; }
```

I've tried to add this directly into the root index.html's head in style tags and into all my components' style tags but simply can't get rid of it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems I was an idiot. When I did the `*{}` rule in my index's head, I never actually included `!important` until I started writing my question, when I didn't remember if the `!important` goes before or after the semi-colon. So after I wrote it in my text editor, copied to my question and then carried on I, for some reason, saved my index and what do you know? It worked.

So in conclusion, `* { margin: 0 !important; }` in style tags in the index.html's head will do the trick.

Comment: Well do you have a better solution? Also, I ended up changing `*` to `body`.

Comment: `body { margin: 0; }` does the job. And if it does not in your project, you need to investigate why.

Comment: @connexo I think your right, this is better than the `*` suggested.  By using the asterisk I was removing all margins in all my tags.  I didnt want that, I think the OP was also asking only for the "initial" margins to be removed.  So thanks.

Comment: You can simply put {display: flex} for the first element in the <template> of the main component ( I have a  component<top></top> inside main). This will remove {display: block (user agent stylesheet)}. I make it forVue 3.

Answer (score 10):

Add style for body element in index.html

`<style> body { margin: 0 !important; } </style>`

example

[image]

Comment: Please insert an example code in a special block, a screenshot of the code is redundant here.

Answer (score 2):

Removing margin didn't work for me. But removing padding worked

```
<style>
     html,body { padding: 0 !important;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because of the "scoped" attribute, remove it in the place where you're setting body margin to 0 and it should work out.

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-top: -0px !important;` in *#app* style works well.

Answer (score 0):

I am using vue3 and I had the same problem. To solve such a problem you can try that:
In public/index.html set id="index" to the body tag and then just define the id as follows:

```
<style lang="scss">
#index {
  margin: 0px !important;
}
</style>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDgN7.png)