# Whats the best practice to use styles in vue components?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

Im using vue cli to create a project but im having 'errors' with the styles

Im just testing a component that have 3 rows 20vh 50vh 30vh

```
<template>
    <div class="gridContact">
        <div class="one">1</div>
        <div class="two">2</div>
        <div class="three">3</div>
    </div>
</template>
<style scoped>
.gridContact {display: grid; grid-template-areas: 'one' 'two' 'three'; box-sizing: border-box;}
    .one {grid-area: one; background: rebeccapurple; box-sizing: border-box; height: 20vh; }
    .two {grid-area: two; background: cadetblue;  box-sizing: border-box; height:50vh;}
    .three {grid-area: three; background: coral;  box-sizing: border-box; height: 30vh; }
</style>
```

And my app.vue

```
*{padding: 0; margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

I got this style (the style needed)

[image]

But if i refresh the page i got this white space that brokes the style, and then if reload sometime again it looks good, and then if i refresh i got the same white space, why?

[image]

Checking this behavior on the developer tools i saw this attribute injected, of course that margin its not inserted by me, i think this is a behavior made it in vue, maybe the scoped attribute?but why ? whats for? how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Have you used devtools to see what's filling that space?

Comment: of course, it says html, but as you can see in the code, i dont see reason why this happen @Daniel_Knights

Comment: I can't see why either. Try using `height: 100vh` on `gridContact` then use percentages on the children

Comment: I tried that too. The weird thing is that it work, but after refresh broke, then after refresh work an so on..

Comment: i updated the post with new content @Daniel_Knights

Comment: Just add `margin: 0` to the body

Comment: Ok but why is this happening? I want to know that

Comment: According to W3 the default margin for the body is `8px`: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216423/discussion-between-alex-hunter-and-daniel-knights).

Comment: Yes i know that too, but i think its a vue 'error' because i did the same exercise with vanilla html and that 'error' doesnt show, well ill make that work around but i really want to know the real explanation in vue. Thanks for the help

Comment: It would be because styling included in the vue app is actually scoped to the app only, not the whole page. Therefore, your '*' rule won't apply to the body for the page (this is my guess at least)

Comment: i tried adding the * to the component and it brokes sometimes too @jkoestinger

Comment: I'll just add that in our larger vue projects - we remove the scoped attr. It fights the cascade and totally blow the whole purpose of how we write styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you don't know from where body's `margin-bottom` is applying, like in below example I intentionally added `margin-bottom` to body and applied your styles too.

```css
.gridContact {display: grid; grid-template-areas: 'one' 'two' 'three'; box-sizing: border-box;}
    .one {grid-area: one; background: rebeccapurple; box-sizing: border-box; height: 20vh; }
    .two {grid-area: two; background: cadetblue;  box-sizing: border-box; height:50vh;}
    .three {grid-area: three; background: coral;  box-sizing: border-box; height: 30vh; }

body{
  margin-bottom:50px;
}

*{padding: 0px; margin: 0px; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="gridContact">
      <div class="one">1</div>
      <div class="two">2</div>
      <div class="three">3</div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Now I Included `!important` to apply my css style forcefully and it worked.

```css
.gridContact {display: grid; grid-template-areas: 'one' 'two' 'three'; box-sizing: border-box;}
    .one {grid-area: one; background: rebeccapurple; box-sizing: border-box; height: 20vh; }
    .two {grid-area: two; background: cadetblue;  box-sizing: border-box; height:50vh;}
    .three {grid-area: three; background: coral;  box-sizing: border-box; height: 30vh; }

body{
  margin-bottom:50px;
}

*{padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="gridContact">
      <div class="one">1</div>
      <div class="two">2</div>
      <div class="three">3</div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: hello, i did this too and you know what? if a refresh the page (f5) multiple times the margin comes back, could this be a vue error?

Comment: multiple times means it is something cache issue, If you press ctrl+f5 you will get same result each time.

Comment: i delete the cache, now ill try creating a new project

Answer (score 4):

In Vue when we use a scoped attribute with style tag, then the CSS will apply only to the current components.

As you declared the margin in the *{} and it is not working because of the same thing of using the scoped attribute with the style tag.

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements

You can use **!important** with the margin property in *{}.

[Vue.js 2 - Remove initial margin from body tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240969/vue-js-2-remove-initial-margin-from-body-tag)

You can also go through this link:
https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/01/vue-js-cant-help-head-body/

Comment: hello, i did this too and you know what? if a refresh the page (f5) multiple times the margin comes back, could this be a vue error?

Answer (score 2):

If the margin is injected automatically, you check the app in all browsers.
Because some browsers inject margin bottom automatically.

You can prevent it by adding,
{margin-bottom: 0 !important} to that component

or

#app {height: 100vh}

Comment: I added that style property and still inject the margin, and for the app height, I just want to add that height to some components, not the entire app